# Как сделать систему подписок для телеграм бота на telebot с sqlite3?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, sqlite3

у меня есть оплата через телеграм, мне нужно сперва занести в БД id пользователя и время на какое время он купил подписку, потом проверку имеется ли человек в БД чтобы дать доступ к ветке сообщений, использую библиотеку telebot с БД sqlite3
если подробнее
пользователь нажимает старт и выбирает Софт, есть на выбор несколько вариантов, бесплатный и платный, пользователь выбирает платный, но его нет в БД, бот предлагает купить ему подписку на 1д, 1н, 1м
пользователь переходит и оплачивает, бот записывает пользователя в БД. по истечению времени удаляет
Я не знаю как это сделать, пытался изучить но не была того что мне нужно было

Comment: Не может быть такого, чтобы не было ничего вообще. Достаточно стандартный набор действий. Делайте код с тем, что нашли, помещайте его здесь, отметьте, что именно не получается или что именно не нашли. Иначе это = "сделайте за меня мою работу".

Answer (score 0):

Что именно необходимо? Код бота? Код запроса к sqlite3? Постановка вопроса, сказать честна, оставляет желать лучшего. Если нужен код проверки наличия пользователя в бд-шке, то вот:

```py
def search_user(user_id: int) -> bool:
    if list(cursor.execute(f'SELECT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = {user_id})').fetchall()[0])[0] == 1:
        return True
    return False
```

Проверять, купил ли пользователь подписку, можно при получении сообщения от оного. То есть, пользователь написал -> бот посмотрел, есть ли такой в БД. Если же тебе надо периодическая проверка действия подписки, то пиши соответствующий код.

Comment: мне нужен код внесения пользователя в БД и проверку, мне нужно чтобы бот через время после того как пользователь купил подписку, удалял из БД когда она закончится

Comment: Код для внесения пользователя в бд я вам дал. Дальше разберетесь сами. Сергей правильно написал вам выше, ваш вопрос выглядит как "Сделайте все за меня!". Гуглите sqlite3 execute. Удачи.